# Cant update, delete records or access database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to create a program which allows users to delete an update lecturers from a lecturers table. For some reason the table which my program displays is not accurate(e.g older values than current table). And i cannot delete or update. I have been stuck on this for quite a while and apologies if it is a simple solution i am only a beginner.

```
<?php
//includes
include("CONFIG/connection.php");  //include the database connection 
include("LIBRARY/helperFunctionsTables.php");  //include the database connection 
include("LIBRARY/helperFunctionsDatabase.php"); //include the database   connection 
require_once("CONFIG/config.php");  //include the application configuration   settings
?>

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo __CSS; ?>
    </head>
    <body>

    <header>

    </header>
    <?php


include("PAGE_CONTENT/navigation.php");

//----------------MAIN SECTION----------------------------//
//========================================================//
echo "<section class='wide'>";
$table = 'lecturer';  //table to delete records from
$PK = "LectID";  //Specify the PK of the table

if (isset($_POST['delrecord']))  //if the form has been submitted 
{
    //DELETE query
    $selectedID = $_POST['delrecord'];  //get the ID of the record we want to     delete from the form
    $sqlDel = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $PK='$selectedID'";  //create the SQL

    if (deleteRecord($conn, $sqlDel))  //call the deleteRecord() function
    {
        echo "<h3>RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID DELETED</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3 >RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID CANNOT BE DELETED</h3>";
    }

    //Re-display table with delete options
    //Query string
    $sqlData = "SELECT * FROM $table";  //get the data from the table
    $sqlTitles = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";  //get the table column descriptions

    //execute the 2 queries
    $rsData = getTableData($conn, $sqlData);
    $rsTitles = getTableData($conn, $sqlTitles);

    //check the results
    $arrayData = checkResultSet($rsData);
    $arrayTitles = checkResultSet($rsTitles);

    //use resultsets to generate HTML tables with DELETE button
    generateDeleteTable($table, $PK, $arrayTitles, $arrayData);

    //close the connection
    $conn->close();
} else if (isset($_POST['editrecord']))  //if the form has been submitted 
{
    echo "am in inside";
    //DELETE query
    $selectedID = $_POST['editrecord'];  //get the ID of the record we want to    delete from the form
    $sqlEDIT = "SELECT FROM $table WHERE $PK='$selectedID'";  //create the SQL

    if (deleteRecord($conn, $sqlEDIT))  //call the deleteRecord() function
    {
        echo "<h3>RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID DELETED</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3 >RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID CANNOT BE DELETED</h3>";
    }
    include 'FORMS/newUserForm.html';

    $lectFirstName = $_POST[lectFirstName];
    $lectLastName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['fName']);

    $sqlEdit = "UPDATE $table SET FirstName=lectFirstName, LastName=lectLastName       WHERE $PK='$selectedID'";


    if (deleteRecord($conn, $sqlEDIT))  //call the deleteRecord() function
    {
        echo "<h3>RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID DELETED</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3 >RECORD WITH PK=$selectedID CANNOT BE DELETED</h3>";
    }


    //Re-display table with delete options
    //Query string
    $sqlData = "SELECT * FROM $table";  //get the data from the table
    $sqlTitles = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";  //get the table column descriptions

    //execute the 2 queries
    $rsData = getTableData($conn, $sqlData);    
    $rsTitles = getTableData($conn, $sqlTitles);

    //check the results
    $arrayData = checkResultSet($rsData);
    $arrayTitles = checkResultSet($rsTitles);

    //use resultsets to generate HTML tables with DELETE button
    generateDeleteTable($table, $PK, $arrayTitles, $arrayData);

    //close the connection
    $conn->close();
} else //this is the first time the form is loaded
{
    //display table with delete options
    //Query string

    $sqlData = "SELECT * FROM $table";  //get the data from the table
    $sqlTitles = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";  //get the table column descriptions


    //execute the 2 queries
    $rsData = getTableData($conn, $sqlData);
    $rsTitles = getTableData($conn, $sqlTitles);

    //check the results
    $arrayData = checkResultSet($rsData);
    $arrayTitles = checkResultSet($rsTitles);

    //use resultsets to generate HTML tables with DELETE button
    generateDeleteTable($table, $PK, $arrayTitles, $arrayData);

    //close the connection
    $conn->close();
}

echo "</section>";
```

Comment: <form  class="small_button" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <button class="smallBtn" name="delrecord" type="submit" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $buttonText; ?></button>
</form>   both buttons are the same aprt from the other is named editrecord

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query. You're doing manual escaping here and forgot to do it on one of your variables. This is exactly why using string interpolation is super dangerous.

Comment: This code is vulerable against SQL injection. But we can't really help you without seeing those helper-functions.

Comment: Need to show us the contents of (at least) LIBRARY/helperFunctionsDatabase.php & preferably the relevant bits of all the included files, before anyone can help. All your DB code is in there somewhere

Comment: You have "DELETE FROM $table WHERE $PK='$selectedID'" and later on PK=$selectedID. Is $PK giving the primary key or should it be PK?